# Unknown SSL certificate showing up on ssllabs.com server test

Tags: php, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've recently ran a SSL test (ssllabs.com/ssltest) on our website: **kimarineadventures.com.au**

Two certificates showed up from different servers. (first one is ours) I'm looking for a solution on how to remove the other one. This is causing errors to some users (website loads unsecure).

Comment: Your domain is set up in the DNS to resolve to an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address. If the IPv6 entry points to the wrong server, then you should either get it corrected, if your server is reachable via IPv6 - or get it removed otherwise.

Comment: With the currently provided information it is unclear if this is a configuration problem in your DNS (IPv4 and IPv6 pointing to a different server) or in your web server (different configurations for IPv4 and IPv6) or even both. Which means you need to fix either your DNS setup and/or your web server setup. More details cannot be provided about this due to a lack of details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain was registered through crazydomains.com.au , and they manage your domain's DNS as well. The second IP address you see on the ssllabs.com report is one of theirs.

To solve the problem you'll need to log on to crazydomains.com.au, open the DNS settings and delete the AAAA record(s) with that IP address (2404:8280:a222:bbbb:bba1:78:ffff:ffff). Leave the A record(s) as they are, and don't touch anything else.

It may take a few minutes to take effect, but that should do it.